# Jquery - Can we change onchange event in select tag by .attr?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<select id=test onchange="foo(1)"> <option value=1>test 1</option> <option value=2>test 2</option> </select>
```

I am trying to change the onchange function using the following:

```
$('#test').attr('onchange','foo(2)'); //this is not working
```

Comment: Avoid inline JavaScript, especially as you're using jQuery.

Comment: works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/WmWLC/

Comment: try wrapping your code inside DOM ready handler, maybe?!...

Answer (score 1):

You should try to change the listener itself instead of trying to change the attribute:

```
$('#test').change(function() {
  alert( "Change Event triggered" );
});
```

If you want to be sure to clean up before to be shure that the listener you attach is the only one attached from that moment on use

```
$("#test").unbind();
```

before you set the new listener.

Edit:
As mentioned in the comments you should not use inline javascript if you want to use the jQuery `unbind` function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using jQuery only ?

```
$("#test").unbind("change");
$("#test").change(function(){
    foo(2);
});
```

Comment: `foo(1)` will still be fired

Comment: `unbind` works only for handler bound using jquery method, not online script

Comment: Since he use jQuery, inline Javascript is useless I think

Comment: use $("#test").removeAttr('onchange');
then use the 
$("#test").change(function(){
    foo(2);
});
it works fine

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#test').change(function() {
    foo(($this).val());
});
```

And remove onchange from the select tag

Comment: Note, this answer will require `onchange="foo(1)"` to be removed, otherwise both will fire.

Comment: @MackieeE, Yes.. have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same question,you may try this

```
$('#test').attr('onChange','foo(2)');
```

using "onChange" instead of "onchange";